# Referring to the same template

Tags: jsrender

That's how I render my templates (on click on some elements of my page)

```
$("[entity]").click(function(e) {
   var entityType = $(this).data('type')
   var source   = $(`#${entityType}Tmpl`).html();
   var tmpl = $.templates(source);
   $("#details").html(tmpl.render(getData(entityType));
});
```

I'm wondering if there is a jsRender way to define a single template for two entityType, something like:

```
<script id="entity1;entity2" type="text/x-jsrender">type: {{:entityType}} </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the entityType as a helper.

```
var helplers = {
  type: entityType,
  getValue: myGetValFunction,
  ...
};

var html = tmpl.render(getData(entityType), helpers);

$("#details").html(html);
```

Then make your template render output based on the type:

```
<script id="tmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
  type:
  ... 
  {{if ~type==='foo}}...{{/if}}
  ...
  {{:~getValue(~type)}}
  ...
</script>
```

http://www.jsviews.com/#helpers

Comment: I already have entityType in my data, the fact is I have several templates (1 per entityType), the only exception is 2 entityType should points to the same template, there is no other way that check the value inside the template (or check in the click handler)?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean, or what problem you are trying to solve.   You could try providing a jsfiddle skeleton example showing your data structure and how you are invoking templates - and clarifying what the problem is. In the template you can check the data you passed it, and you can check any other values you need, by passing them as helpers. What else do you need?!